# can't bind $parent of knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I'm new to KnockOut and I have a model like this:

```
let viewModel = {
    teams: ko.observableArray([]),
    employees: ko.observableArray([]),
    projects: ko.observableArray([])
}
```

I have a `div` with a `data-bind="foreach: teams"`. However, inside that `div` when I try to use the `$parent`, for example:

```
data-bind="text: $parent.employees[0].FirstName"
```

when I try to run it, I get a message like this:

[image]

Anyone knows how to fix this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please, have a look at this link:  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html. In the section 'Reading information from an observableArray' there is an example (`alert`).

Comment: it seems that `employees` has no records, but you need to show us [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help you.

Comment: try this instead `data-bind="text: $parent.employees()[0].FirstName"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-write your binding to

```
data-bind="text: $parent.employees()[0].FirstName"
```

Since you declared employees as an observableArray you have to evaluate it and then you can access the underlying array by using an index.

Remember that:

```
var test = ko.observableArray([]);

console.log(test); // this is a function
console.log(test()); // this is the actual array
```